# How to check if a file is the same file as before

Tags: php

I need to check if a file that existed in a directory on the server is the same file that was there say 5 minutes ago?

On a specific directory, I'm deleting and recreating a file with the same name every few minutes. A script is to access the file say every 2 mins. So at time t, the script checks the file and do stuffs. Then at time t+1, the file is deleted and recreated (same name but maybe different content). Then at time t+2, the script again looks for the file.

So in the second check , is there a way to check whether the file has been changed or not (without having to read the content)??

Comment: You are doing this with what? PHP? Also, why is this tagged "javascript"?

Comment: Some filesystems store a checksum, but you cannot access it from within PHP. The inode check with `stat()` is not a dependable test. But `filemtime()` or better yet `filectime()` is an option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first idea that comes to mind to determine whether a file has changed is to check its modification time, using the [**`filemtime()`**](https://www.php.net/filemtime) function.

But I'm guessing this will not quite work, as you are deleting and re-creating the file regularly.

So, in your case, a very quick *(but not safe, of course)* first way is to **check the size of the file** : if it has changed, it is not the same file.

In PHP, the size of a file can be determined using the [**`filesize()`**][2] function.

Then, if the size has not changed, you'll generally want to **calculate a hash of the file's content** -- which is generally either an [md5][3] or [sha1][4] hash.

In PHP, you'll use one of the following functions, depending on which algorithm you want to work with :

- [**`sha1_file()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1-file.php)
- [**`md5_file()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php)

Answer (score 5):

From PHP, you can use the function [`filemtime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) to get the last-modified timestamp for your file.

**Be careful!**

The return value of this function is cached, and calling it multiple times from the same script will result in the same value being returned *even if the file has changed in the meantime!* To work around this, you need to call [`clearstatcache`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) before calling `filemtime`.

If you are calling `filemtime` *once* in every script (and then the script terminates), this does not affect you and you don't need to do `clearstatcache`.

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate a "fingerprint" of the file using the md5_file() function, which will indicate if the file has been altered.

e.g.

```
<?php

$file1_fp = md5_file($fname1);
$file2_fp = md5_file($fname2);

if ($file1_fp === $file2_fp )
{

  //do something..
}

?>
```

see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php

Answer (score 2):

Use filemtime to check the date the file was last modified.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

Answer (score 0):

If you could trust the **timestamp**, use the **File's timestamp** to differentiate it, otherwise, use **MD5 digest etc** or do a **bit to bit comparison**.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check whether the checksum of the file has changed. This one-liner calculates the MD5 hash:

```
md5(file_get_contents('/path/to/file'))
```

As an alternative, you could (if the OS and FS supports this) rely on file creation datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [`fileinode()`](http://php.net/fileinode). If the file was deleted and recreated the inode will be different even if the file will get identical content.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the calculated MD5 - this should in dicate any changes to the file